# Ooyala video player: notification for fullscreen/inline switch?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ooyala

I am using Ooyala video player in my project, I need a way to detect when the user switch between full screen / inline mode, is there any notification for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your tags, I'm guessing this is for the Ooyala iOS SDK.  You want to add an observer for the OOOoyalaPlayerViewControllerFullscreenEnter and OOOoyalaPlayerViewControllerFullscreenExit notifications on your OOOoyalaPlayerViewController.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? What exactly need to do to get full screen/inline notification? Thanks